# Python confusion - Printing a concise frame stack

Tags: python, stack, frame

I've been stuck on a programming exercise for a while. I have a basic program written and the exercise is asking me to have it print out the frame stack. All methods I've tried have not printed out the information I'm needing.

This is my simple program,

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import math

def square(x): # returns the sqare of x
    return x*x

def hyp(x, y): # returns the size of vector (x,y)
    return math.sqrt(square(x) + square(y))

def compVectLen(x1,y1, x2,y2): # compares the size of two vectors
    return hyp(x1,y1) >= hyp(x2,y2)

print compVectLen(2,2, 7,7)
```

and this is how the exercise is asking for stack frames to be displayed,

```
 |---------------compVectLen---------------­­­­­­­­­­­­­|
 | Locals: x1=2,y1=2, x2=7,y2=7            ­|
 | return hyp(x1,y1) >= hyp(x2,y2)         |
 |­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­-----------------------------------------|
 |­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­---------------hyp(x1, y1)---------------­­­­­­­­­­­­|
 | Locals: x=2,y=2                       ­  |
 | return math.sqrt(square(x) + square(y)) |
 |-----------------------------------------|
 |­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­----------------square(x)----------------­­­­­­­­­­­­­­|
 | Locals: x=2,                          ­  |
 | return 2*2                              |
 |­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­-----------------------------------------|
```

All methods I've tried have given me results but not with as much information and not in this style.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What methods have you tried? Is the exercise asking you to write the output of the stack frame yourself?

Comment: The exercise is worded; "Modify the example program  “compVectLen” in 
slide 32 in order to make it print out, while 
evaluating, stack­frame “debugging” information 
similar to the one printed in slides 34 to 49." As for what I've tried, I've used traceback and inspect and neither have printed a Call Stack like the example asks for...

Answer (score 0):

in your

```
def compVectLen(x1,y1, x2,y2): # compares the size of two vectors
return hyp(x1,y1) >= hyp(x2,y2)
```

you are not giving any conditions. you just return `hyp(x1,y1) >= hyp(x2,y2)` which will always return x1,y1 values to be greater..

Comment: The script just returns true or false depending on what my "print compVectLen(2,2, 7,7)" line says. I'm still at very basic programming exercises.